# Codeigniter view is not loading

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating a simple login site(first step of the project) and I get error regardless of the information I fill in the username and password forms.
this is my code:

**login.php**

```
<?php
class login extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
    }

    function login_control()
    {       
        $data['title'] = "Login page";      
        $this->load->view("loginview", $data);
    }

    function login_validation()  
    {  
       $this->load->library('form_validation');  
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');  
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');  
       if($this->form_validation->run())  
       {  
            //true  
            $username = $this->input->post('username');  
            $password = $this->input->post('password');  
            //model function  
            $this->load->model('server_model');  
            if($this->server_model->can_login($username, $password))  
            {  
                 $session_data = array('username' => $username);  
                 $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);  
                 redirect(base_url() . 'login/enter');  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                 $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Invalid Username and Password');  
                 redirect(base_url() . 'login/login_control');  
            }  
       }  
       else  
       {  
            //false  
            $this->login_control();  
       }  
    }

    function enter()
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('username') != '')
        {

            echo 'Welcome - '. $this->session->userdata('username');
            echo '<label><a href="'.base_url().'login/logout">Logout</a></label>';  
        } 
        else
        {
            redirect(base_url().'login/login_control');
        }
    }
    function logout()  
    {  
       $this->session->unset_userdata('username');  
       redirect(base_url() . 'login/login_control');  
    }
}
```

**server_model.php**

```
<?php
class server extends CI_Model
{
    function can_login($username, $password)
    {
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);
        $query = $this->db->get('users');

        if($query->num_rows()>0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**loginview.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login | <?php echo $title; ?></title>
<link rel ="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class = "container">
<br /><br /> <br />
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>login/login_validation">
    <div class="form-group">  
        <label>Enter Username</label>  
        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" />  
        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('username'); ?>
        </span>                 
    </div> 

    <div class="form-group">  
        <label>Enter Password</label>  
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" />  
        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('password'); ?>
        </span>  
    </div>  
    <div class="form-group">  
        <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Login" class="btn btn-info" />  
        <?php  
        echo '<label class="text-danger">'.$this->session->flashdata("error").'</label>';  
        ?>  
    </div>  
    </form>  
</div>  
</body>  
</html>
```

My `.htaccess` file looks like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

my **routes.php** is like this

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
$route['default_controller'] = 'login/login_control';
$route['login/login_control'] = 'loginview';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

I think the error is probably at my .htaccess or routes files but I have been trying to fix this for hours and I couldnt solve the problem.
Any help appreciated

Comment: Also let me say that this is the first time I am writing php code

Comment: Since you are working first time, you should copy and follow all details from documentation. Saying that, check [naming convention for class names and file names](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/styleguide.html). After that reorder routes and put `$route['login/login_control'] = 'loginview';` at the end leaving default routes on their first positions. After that check if error still exist.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I didnt know a convention like that existed. I tried reordering routes but nothing changed @Tpojka

Comment: Model file name and class name are different in your question. 
Best way would be you set both to be `Server_model` for class and `Server_model.php`.

Comment: @Tpojka it didn't work either. it keeps giving This site can’t be reached

htdocs’s server DNS address could not be found.
Search Google for htdocs codeigniter log validation
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: Localhost or online? What is web location of apache and where is project relative to that?

Comment: Try change login_control() to index()

Comment: @wolfgang1983 no result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I thought the problem was something really stupid of me. I am using Sublime Text so when I save a file I need to also add the extension .php which apparently I hadn't done. Thanks to everyone who tried on solving this problem although there wasn't any real problem out there.